# How to call Rest API post method in salesforce?

Tags: rest-api, php, apexrest

How can I call Rest API post method that has parameters into php codes? . I just want the proper format for calling .

Here is my Code.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Event/*')
global with sharing class AS_EventAndApplication {

@HttpGet
global static void getEventAndApplication()
{       
    //code goes here
}

@HttpPost
global static ResponseHandler post(String eventId, String appFormId, String contactId, String appData)
{
   //code goes here
}
}
```

PHP CODE FOR GET

```
    $query = 'Event';
    $url = $this->instance_url . "/services/apexrest/" . $query;
```

PHP CODE FOR POST ?

```
    $query = '??????<-what should I put here ?? base on my apex rest code above';
    $url = $this->instance_url . "/services/apexrest/" . $query;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest use workbench for testing

https://workbench.developerforce.com/

Above utilities --> click -->Rest explorer

[image]